# Create GPX track in R. writeOGR function

Tags: r, ogr, gpx, tracking, rgdal

I have a gpx file where someone exported two different activities in two separate locations to a single track.  I need to split them and avoid getting the erroneous line in the track layer that connects the two places where they were using the GPS.  I haven't found a method to cut a track at a certain spot, so my approach was to read in the track_points layer, subset for the date I was interested in, and push those points to a spatiallinesdataframe, and write the new track.  I manage to write it without getting an error, but when I try to read it back again, it says there are no features in the track layer. I would be open to any solution that would split the track layer, and if anyone that is already answering this question knows how to write a 'tracks', 'track_points', and 'waypoints' layer to the same .gpx file, please include that in your answer as that will be my next step after solving this problem.

Here's what I did so far:

```
library(rgdal)
gpxfile<-"C:/Users/.../file.gpx"
trackpoints<-readOGR(gpxfile, layer="track_points")

library(lubridate)
trackpoints$time<-ymd_hms(trackpoints$time) 
trackpoints<-trackpoints[trackpoints$time>'2016/03/16 12:00:59+00',] #subset for the date I'm interested in

coord<-as.data.frame(coordinates(trackpoints))
lin<-Line(coord)

lin1<-Lines(list(lin), ID="track")
lin2<-SpatialLines(list(lin1))

df<-data.frame(len=sapply(1:length(lin2), function(i) gLength(lin2[i,])))
rownames(df)<-sapply(1:length(lin2), function(i) lin2@lines[[i]]@ID)

lin3<-SpatialLinesDataFrame(lin2, data=df)

proj4string(lin3)<-CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
names(lin3)<-"name"

writeOGR(lin3,
     dsn="C:/Users/.../newtrack.gpx", layer="tracks", driver="GPX",
     dataset_options="GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=yes", overwrite_layer = T)
```

Comment: Could you post a link to your original data? Your `writeOGR` function looks correct, what happens if you plot `lin3`?

Comment: When I plot lin3, it plots exactly what I want to see.  It's just that when I try to write that to the track layer, it doesn't actually create the feature for some reason.  The script should work for any .gpx file, but here is a link to the one that I am working with:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/45h27qhyywfd1yl/DeerPoint.gpx?dl=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figuring out the [GPX driver options](http://www.gdal.org/drv_gpx.html) for rgdal is headache-inducing.

Writing a linestring as you've done here will cause it to write a route layer - if you write a multilinestring it should create a track layer. According to the documentation you **should** be able to make it be a track layer regardless using `FORCE_GPX_TRACK=true` but I've not been able to make that work with this example.

Some experimentation shows that just writing the track points will automatically create the track line as well, creating a track layer:

```
writeOGR(trackpoints, 
     dsn="lin3_trk.gpx", 
     layer="track_points", 
     driver = "GPX")
```

[image]

Comment: I got the `FORCE_GPX_TRACK=true` to work, but I had to enter it in the argument in a very unintuitive way:


    `writeOGR(lin3,
         dsn="C:/Users/.../file.gpx", layer="tracks", driver="GPX",
         dataset_options="GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=yes","FORCE_GPX_TRACK=true", overwrite_layer = T)`

Comment: and using `"FORCE_GPX_TRACK=true"` I can also just write `layer="track_points"` using my subset of the trackpoints, and it will write both the correct track points layer and the track layer without the need of converting the points into SpatialLines and so forth.

Comment: You don't need to use FORCE_GPX_TRACK if you just write track_points, as per my example!

Comment: Yes, but if I don't use it and I try to read the newly written file into R with `readOGR(file, layer="tracks")` , it will say that there is no feature in the track layer.  With `FORCE_GPX_TRACK` , I can run that and also run it again with `layer="track_points"` and it will read both of them into R.

Answer (score 0):

I tried over and over again to use the above question and answer to export a data frame I had created as a track in a gpx file. I could only get a gpx file that had waypoints (not track points or tracks). The problem I discovered is that a track requries information about the track and segments (track_fid, track_seg_id, track_seg_point_id), not just geographic data.

Here is an example in case someone else is trying to convert a very simple data frame to tracks and track points.

```
#Example DataFrame
Long<-seq(-87.111, -87.121, length.out=100)
Lat<-seq(36.333, 36.323, length.out=100)
Time<-seq(1200,1300, length.out=100)

GeoData<-data.frame(Long,Lat,Time) #Starting DF
GeoData[,"track_fid"]<-0 #Assign ID to tracks
GeoData[,"track_seg_id"]<-0 #Assign_seg_id to segments of tracks
GeoData[,"track_seg_point_id"]<-0:(nrow(GeoData)-1) #Assign point IDs, begin at zero and go in consecutive order. If data is not in order, it will need sorted first.

#Make DF a spatial point data frame
#For the data argument only include columns you wish to maintain in the final gpx file
GeoDataSpatialPoint<-SpatialPointsDataFrame(GeoData[,c("Long","Lat")], data = GeoData[,c(4:6)], proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

library(rgdal)
writeOGR(GeoDataSpatialPoint, dsn = "FinalTrackFile.gpx", layer = "track_points",
         dataset_options="GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=yes", driver = "GPX", overwrite_layer = T)

#make sure the file saved and has the expected geometry types (in this case, 100 track points and 1 track)
library(sf)
st_layers("FinalTrackFile.gpx")
```